# How to use the values from an array defined in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, core-plot

I followed John Wordsworth tutorial (http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/10/adding-charts-to-your-iphone-ipad-app-using-core-plot/) to produce a line graph with CorePlot.

Later I decided to get some JSON data from a website so that I can use it for my graph.

All the url connection methods are performed in my `ViewController.m` file. And there I created an NSArray called `indicator` containing all the JSON data.

My problem is that all of the graph's parameters are defined in a separate NSObject class called `SimpleScatterPlot.m` where I would like to use the array of strings "`indicator`" (defined in `ViewController.m`) to customize the x-Axis labels.

What do I have to do so that I can use this JSON data array in `SimpleScatterPlot.m`?
I tried `#import "ViewController.h"` but it did not solve it.

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can give me.

Comment: you will have to create instance of `viewController` in order to access its ivar in `SimpleScatterView`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C
Read it. You can use:
1. Properties
2. Method that return an object
3. Singleton to get needed instance
5. Protocol
6...

Depend on your requirements...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding it correctly, but I think you have not try to access the indicator nsarray from SimpleScatterView.m but to set there the value from ViewController.m.

1) Define a public NSArray in SimpleScatterView.m and synthesize it.

2) Instead of trying to gain access, use "prepareForSegue" in ViewControler.m to set indicator in the destinationSegueController.

3) In SimpleScatterView.m implement "-(void)setIndicator:(NSArray *)indicator" and update the GUI as needed.

Although the "Model - View - Controller" paradigm recommends not to use ViewControllers to perform communications and so on, but that is for another thread.

Comment: The project I'm building is a single view app which contains a UIView that holds the SimpleScatterPlot. So there are no segues involved.

Answer (score 0):

If I do not read incorrectly what you are trying to do, my guess is that you could appropriately use `SimpleScatterView` from within your `UIViewController` view (this is, assuming that `SimpleScatterView` is actually a `UIView`).

In this case, when your controller has downloaded its data, you could instantiate `SimpleScatterView` and display it by adding it to your view controller `view`.

```
... <data has been downloaded> ...
SimpleScatterView* scatterView = [[SimpleScatterView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
[self.view addSubview:scatterView];
```

When you initialize your `SimpleScatterView`, you could pass it a reference to the data array (say, in its custom init method, or using a property). e.g.:

```
SimpleScatterView* scatterView = [[SimpleScatterView alloc] initWithFrame:... andData:(NSArray*)...];
```

or:

```
scatterView.dataSet = <your_json_array>;
```

Of course, you have plenty of alternatives to this design. Specifically, I would mention:

1. the possibility of using a model class to handle all of your data, such that the controller writes the data to the model, while the plot view reads the data from it. The model could be implemented though a singleton in this case for ease of access;
2. the possibility of using a "dataSource" for your plot view: this would entail defining a protocol between the view and its datasource (e.g., a `getData` method); your view controller would play the role of the data source (in other words, instead of passing the array to the plot view as in above example, you would pass a reference to the controller and the view would access its data).

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in Viewcontroller and synthesize it. Then pass the JSON data to the property.

```
To access the array in SimpleScatterView.m:
    Viewcontroller *viewcontrol = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    You can then access the array by using viewcontrol.indicator.
    NSLog(@"%@",viewcontrol.indicator);
```

Comment: I tried this but I get errors when I try to build the project. I believe in order to use that code you provided I had to #import "ViewController.h". The thing is, my code already imports SimpleScatterPlot.h into the ViewController.h... seems redundant and I think this is what I causing the errors.